# Get 2d Affine transformation from 2 pair of points Matlab

Tags: matlab, transformation, matrix-multiplication, affinetransform

I have matrix with 5 points in homogeneous coordinates x1(x1; y1; z1).. x4(x4; y4; z4). I know that after applying Affine transformation to this matrix x1 moved to x1_prime, x2 - to x2_prime. How can I find the transformation matrix?

I tried

```
X = [x1 x2];
X_prime = [x1_prime x2_prime];
T = X_prime/X;
```

But this does not work. After I apply T on my 4 points I get 1 segment.

[image]

I tried fitgeotrans() in Matlab, but I suppose I have used it incorrect.
Could you please help me to find Affine transformation matrix in Matlab?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 2 points it is impossible to find Affine transformation matrix

```
 [a b c;
  d e f; 
  g h i].
```

We need 3 points for it. Only then for each line of matrix we will have 3 unknowns and 3 equations.
With 2 points we can find

```
[a b;
 d e]
```

part of matrix, then add  0 0 1's and we will get Affine transformation

```
   [a b 0;
    d e 0;
    0 0 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The matrix you're trying to solve for is a 3x3 matrix. But you've packed your data into a 1x15 matrix, instead of a 3x5 matrix which will allow you to backsolve easily.
Try this :

```
X = [x1;x2;x3;x4;x5];
X_prime = [x1_prime;x2_prime;...];
T = X_prime/X;
```

Comment: Sorry, I wrote incorrect.I use x1(x1; y1; z1), so my points are columns. So `x1 = [1; 0; 1];
    x2 = [0; 1; 1];
    x1_new = [2; 0; 1];
    x2_new = [-1; 1; 1];

    X = [x1 x2];
    X_new = [x1_new x2_new];
    T = X_new/X;`   After this my T matrix contains zeroes in second column, does not look like affine transformation at all